# Chinese Hub identification help?

Tags: identify-this-bike, cyclocross, freehub

I bought some carbon cyclocross wheels in 2014 on ebay from seller diybike. (listing long gone).

After 13,000km the freehub body has seen better days. Trying to source a replacement without swapping out the entire hub.

It's a 3 pawl, 24h , 135mm QR, 6 bolt disc brake hub, 10/11spd shimano hub. No identifiable markings. Has a 15mm axle the enduro 6802LLB bearings ride on.

I've seen DT swiss freehubs that look close but they don't seem to have the bearing nearest the pawls protruding.

Any ideas?

Few images here: https://photos.app.goo.gl/xo5ZfzAHccafiCwG7
[image: freehub]

Comment: I think it might be http://www.power-way.com.tw/PFH-CX27A.htm

Comment: Good luck with the search. TIme for a new wheel